# Horde Login Failed

Tags: horde

I did the setup on my machine, but I can't log in at all.
I tried to use the "secret_key" which is in the config.php file or even the local user of the machine.
any tips?

test.php?app=passwd

```
Passwd Version
H5 (5.0.7)
PHP Version
View phpinfo() screen
View loaded extensions
PHP Version: 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
PHP Major Version: 7.2
PHP Minor Version: 19
PHP Subminor Version: 0ubuntu0.18.04.2
PHP Version Classification: release
This version of PHP has not been fully tested with this version of Horde.
PHP Module Capabilities
Ctype Support: Yes
```

Authentication

```
$conf['auth']['driver'] = 'imap';
$conf['auth']['params'] = array(
    'hostspec' => '192.168.0.42',
    'port' => 143,
    'secure' => 'none'
);
```

PHP: 7+2
Horde: 5.2.22
Ubuntu: 18.04.2

Comment: Take a look at the *Authentication* section on the [Horde HowTo Documentation](https://wiki.horde.org/HowTo).

Comment: Thank you, I follow this link by adding the imap drive, but now it returns invalid login or password.
Ps: I can authenticate this email via Android App